# Referencing of classes and namespaces Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I noticed for my little project that when importing  classes some use full folder reference while otheres don't.
Here is code from project Mini that i am working on.

**Models folder**
Contains two entities, Auto and Airplane

```
namespace Mini.Models {
     public class Auto {
         // code and stuff
     }
}

namespace Mini.Models {
     public class Airplane {
         // code and stuff
     }
}
```

**Services folder** Contains single service class

```
namespace Mini.Services
{
   public class AutoService : IAutoService {
      public bool Get() {
            var autoObject = new Models.Auto();   // notice how it references Models folder
            var planeObject = new Airplane();  // Same folder but not referencing Models in front of it      
            // other code
      }
   }

   public interface IAutoService {
      bool Get();
      // others
   }
}
```

While not a major bugbear, it is still annoying that two classes in same folder get referenced differently, and i cannot figure out why.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Error Message when removing Models folder**

```
Error CS0118: 'Auto' is a namespace but is used like a type (34, 27)
```

Comment: Note that you're talking about namespaces, and not folders. They are two different concepts, and only namespaces have a bearing on your code. Now, what do you mean by "it references Models folder"? How did you produce this code?

Comment: Ignore that, quick typing. Meant to be folders. References folders when instantiating Auto() class. I produced the code by typing it up, no autogen.

Comment: If you remove `Models.` from `Models.Auto`, it will still compile, assuming that you are referencing the same `Airplane` on the line below. The only reasons I can see for requiring `Models.Auto` are: 1) You hadn't added a `using` for the `Mini.Models` namespace when you wrote that line of code, or 2) You have another class called `Auto` within the `Mini` or `Mini.Services` namespaces, and you needed to type `Models.Auto` in order to disambiguate it.

Comment: Tried that, didn't compile :(, everything is the same between the classes now

Comment: Didn't compile? Show the error.

Comment: check if there any other "Auto" class exist, is it an ambiguous reference? If yes then try to give a different name to "Auto" class.

Comment: The namespace prefix is sometimes necessary to disambiguate namespace collisions. My guess is that your project includes a `Mini.Services.Auto` class but not a `Mini.Services.Airplane` class..

Comment: I put in the error message i get from compilation when i remove Models. Also there are no other instances of Auto. There is only one project in the whole solution. Only two classes in Models folder and 1 service class in services folder. Services class is called by ValuesController. it is setup as s singleton AddScoped<IAutoService, AutoService>(); in Startup.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message you have provided:

```
Error CS0118: 'Auto' is a namespace but is used like a type (34, 27)
```

It would appear that you have a namespace called `Auto`. Imagine the following example:

```
namespace MyApp.Auto
{
    class Test
    {
    }
}

namespace MyApp
{
    class Auto
    {
    }

    class MyTest
    {
        private Auto test;
    }
}
```

Because you can see, from the `MyApp` namespace, both a class called `Auto` and a namespace called `Auto` (either `namespace MyApp.Auto` or simply `namespace Auto`), C# isn't sure which one you want. As such, it's forcing you to be specific in choosing one or the other.

The easiest solution is to change the `MyApp.Auto` namespace to something else.

Comment: there are only 3 classes i added, AutoService, Auto, Airplane. There are no other classes that i added (even via nuget). I just checked object browser, and there are no duplications of Auto anywhere.

Comment: you can also test it by giving a different name to "AUTO" class, and then check if the same scenario persists or not.

Comment: Are you perhaps referencing a library that provides an `Auto` namespace?

Comment: @Aeseir - the C# compiler disagrees with you, and it doesn't tend to make mistakes. If you enter `var a = new Auto.` in a method, what does Intellisense show you on hitting the `.`?

Comment: I believe @John is correct, one more way to check is to type `Auto` and let Intellisense tells you which namespace it is (it should show the double curly brackets icon for namespace).

Comment: It was the first thing i checked. No other entities, namespaces or even folders/files with Auto in them. IntelliSense points to my class and only my class. This is why i am finding it so confusing. Logically (at least from what i can see and follow here) it shouldn't be occuring. I recreated the solution from scratch with same classes and it doesn't do it.

Comment: Can you commit the original to a GitHub repo so that I can take a look?

Comment: i think there was something wrong with VS2017. I started a new solution exactly the same, copied the files over, and they all nice and proper. Must be something in one of the confg files regarding namespaces that caused this. Thanks for the guidance appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not fix but explaining with proper code sample (and why ).

```
namespace Mini.Models
{
    public class Auto
    {
        // code and stuff
    }
}

namespace Mini.Models
{
    public class Airplane
    {
        // code and stuff
    }
}

namespace Mini.Auto
{
    public class OtherAirplane
    {
        // code and stuff
    }
}

namespace Mini
{
    using Mini.Models;
    using namespaceAuto = Auto ; /// this also not fix the issue.

    class NamespaceIssue
    {
        void execute()
        {
            var autoObject = new Auto();   // Error 
            var planeObject = new Airplane();  // Same folder but not referencing Models in front of it      
            // other code
        }
    }
}
```

now you can see some were in code you have "Mini.Auto" namespace , and it is couching issue.

i tested for VS 2015 have same issue. maybe we have to report to VS team or it is by design .

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be with VS2017 or the way it created the project first time around.

Upon starting brand new project (ASP Core 2.2, Web API, with https enabled and docker disabled), and using same classes the issue was non-existant.